# How to write every second line in python 3?

Tags: python

```
def every_second_line(report):
    """ (Open File for reading) -> list of str

    Return a list containing every second line (with leading and trailing
    whitespace removed) in report, starting with the first line.
    """
    list=[]
    for line in report:
        list.append(line.strip)
    report.readline()
    return list
```

I just came across this code while I was reviewing for my exam. Can someone please tell me why this code is not working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well I'm guessing at least partly because it specifically asks for every *second* line, but that's not what's in the list.

Comment: I bet `readline` is in there so the file pointer moves forward, but it's not doing much when it's indented to be outside the loop.

Comment: You are also never calling `line.strip`; a list of references to a built-in method is not what is asked for either.

Comment: And don't name a list list

Comment: Here is an alternative function that does what you want: `def every_second_line(report): return list(map(str.strip, list(report)[::2]))`

Answer (score 3):

The minimal change to your code is just to put `report.readline()` inside the `for` loop.

```
for line in report:
    lst.append(line.strip())
    report.readline()
```

You could also use `next(report)` (which works for all iterators, not just file objects) instead of `report.readline()`.

Note that if your file has an odd number of lines, that `report.readline()` might throw a `StopIteration` error (or is it `EOFError`?) Best to catch that.

```
for line in report:
    lst.append(line.strip())
    try:
        next(report)
    except (StopIteration, EOFError): # because I don't remember which it throws
        break # leave the for loop
```

Or as JuniorCompressor notes in the comments, you can use the optional argument to `next` to ignore completely

```
for line in report:
    lst.append(line.strip())
    next(report, None)
```

Comment: You can specify `next(report, None)` to silently ignore?

Comment: @JuniorCompressor I always forget you can do that. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! list=[]
    for line in report:
        list.append(line.strip())
        report.readline()
    return list

Answer (score 2):

You can slice using `itertools.islice` with a step of 2 using `map` to `str.strip` each line:

```
from itertools import islice

with open(fle) as f:
    print(list(map(str.strip,islice(f,0,None,2))))
```

If you want every second line from the second start from 1:

```
 print(list(map(str.strip,islice(f,1,None,2))))
```

According to your specification you are meant to open a file which I don't see you doing.

In your own code if you actually have a file object passed you just need to call next on the file object and actually call `strip` with parens:

```
    lst=[]
    for line in report:
        lst.append(line.strip()) # to call strip you need parens
        next(report,"")
    return lst
```

Put `next` before  `lst.append` if you want every second line starting from the second. `next` takes a default value so we pass an empty string to avoid a stopIteration error in case we run out of lines before and still call next.

Comment: I actually haven't learned next function yet, is there a way to just work this question out with only readline, strip and for loop ?

Comment: @Carlos, replace next with `f.readline()` it will do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

try this to get every `2nd` element in list:

```
for line in report[::2]:
```

If you dont want `1st line`

```
for line in report[1::2]:
```

Considering if `report` is `generator object`:

Simply call `list`

```
for line in list(report)[::2]:
```

IF report must act as a `generator`(huge file), then

```
try:
    for x in report:
        line = next(report)
        list.append(line.strip()) #dont use list as variable name
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Comment: I thought iterators can't be sliced

Answer (score 0):

list=[]
    for line in report:
        list.append(line.strip())
        report.readline()
    return list
This is the right version. Thanks! Guys